# Java Error : javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, jtable

What I'm trying to do is I am creating a `JTable` inside a new instance of `JPanel` and `JFrame` and I am getting the error upon adding the rows in the table:

```
Object[] column = {"id", "title"};
Object[][] data = {};
JTable toDoTable = new JTable(data, column) {
  public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex,
      int columnIndex) {
       if(columnIndex == 1) {
          setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
       } else {
           setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       }

         return super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);
  }
};


JScrollPane jpane = new JScrollPane(toDoTable);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(new Dimension(1100, 408));
frame.setTitle("JTable Font Setting Example");
panel.add(jpane);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
frame.setVisible(true);

// Add rows in the Table
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)toDoTable.getModel();
ConnectMSSQLServer connServer = new ConnectMSSQLServer();
ResultSet rs = connServer.dbConnect();
  try
   {
      while (rs.next()) {
          String id = rs.getString("id");
          String title = rs.getString("title");
          model.addRow(new Object[]{id, title});
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

The error occurs in the add rows in table

Comment: This is because `getModel()` returns a `TableModel`, which is not necessarily an instance of `DefaultTableModel`. Presumably you'd need to call `toDoTable.setModel`, passing an instance of `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks but I don't fully understand it. I'm new to Java and learning things out. Any suggestion how to fix it? All I'm doing is adding rows in the table

Comment: Share the code where you *create* toDoTable - if you set a DefaultTableModel there, you can retrieve it later. OR if you want to *initialize* the table from the DB, just create a *new* DefaultTableModel and set that into your table

Comment: @Jan I have all the code above. I am creating the table first. Then query the rows in the database then add the rows to the table. You can re recheck my code above. thanks

Comment: in that case - check my answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are invoking the [`JTable(Object[][], Object[])`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JTable.java#683) constructor. If you check out the source code in that link, you can see that it is invoking the `JTable(TableModel)` constructor internally, having constructed an anonymous instance of `AbstractTableModel`, which is what is returned by the `getModel()` method - this can't be cast to a `DefaultTableModel`.

However: what you are trying to do here won't work anyway. You are saying that the rows of the data are represented by a zero-element array:

```
Object[][] data = {};
```

You will not be able to add rows to this, because you can't resize an array once constructed.

Instead of this, you should construct an explicit `DefaultTableModel`:

```
TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(column, rowCount);
```

and then use this to construct the `JTable`:

```
JTable toDoTable = new JTable(tableModel) { ... }
```

I am not familiar with swing at all, but it looks like `DefaultTableModel` is backed by a `Vector` for the row data, so you don't need to know the exact value of `rowCount` up front.

Comment: Thanks. It works now just what you suggsted. Thanks for the explanation too :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this slightly changed code:

```
    //Create the new model for the table
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    ConnectMSSQLServer connServer = new ConnectMSSQLServer();
    //Try with catch for auto-closing result set
    try(ResultSet rs = connServer.dbConnect()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("id");
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            model.addRow(new Object[] { id, title });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //HANDLE THIS!
    }
    //Now populate the table with the new model
    toDoTable.setModel(model);
```